# Upgrading mysql percona server from 5.5.40 to 5.6.71

Tags: mysql, replication, upgrade, percona

```
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.file_summary_by_event_name is wrong. Expected 23, found 5. Created with MySQL 50540, now running 50621. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.file_summary_by_instance is wrong. Expected 25, found 6. Created with MySQL 50540, now running 50621. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'host_cache' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.mutex_instances: expected column 'LOCKED_BY_THREAD_ID' at position 2 to have type bigint(20), found type int(11).
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'objects_summary_global_by_type' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.rwlock_instances: expected column 'WRITE_LOCKED_BY_THREAD_ID' at position 2 to have type bigint(20), found type int(11).
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_actors' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_objects' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_io_waits_summary_by_table' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_lock_waits_summary_by_table' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.threads is wrong. Expected 14, found 3. Created with MySQL 50540, now running 50621. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_current' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_history' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_history_long' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_stages_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_current' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_history' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_history_long' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_digest' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'users' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'accounts' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'hosts' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'socket_instances' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'socket_summary_by_instance' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'socket_summary_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_connect_attrs' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_account_connect_attrs' has the wrong structure
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-12-26 05:18:20 13215 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.21-70.1-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release 70.1, Revision 698
```

Comment: This is just an error log. What did you do? What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

The solution appears to be presented to you multiple times in the log file you posted.

```
Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
```

> mysql_upgrade examines all tables in all databases for incompatibilities with the current version of MySQL Server. mysql_upgrade also upgrades the system tables so that you can take advantage of new privileges or capabilities that might have been added.
>
> — http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html

This is also mentioned in the Percona in-place upgrade docs: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/upgrading_guide_55_56.html